# pyfinance module. rolling OLS - min window needed

Tags: python, regression, linear-regression

i'm tring to do a simple linear regression using pyfinance package and using PandasRollingOLS to have rolling regression beta (rolling with min_window option).

it works but i would like to have a min_window in the function.

i would like to have min_window in the rollingOLS function, because if we have a window of 90 it does not perform OLS on first 90 values. i would like to perform a OLS expanding until 90 observations starting when there is at least 12 observation (min_window), then rolling of 90 (window)

i tried to understand the code of the package but i'm not able to include min_window in the code.

i would like this kind of function (this is init of PandasRollingOLS class):

```
def __init__(self, y, x=None, window=None, **min_window=None**, has_const=False, use_const=True):
```

i think i should update the code on utils.rolling_windows posted below, can someone help me please?

```
def rolling_windows(a, window):
"""Creates rolling-window 'blocks' of length `window` from `a`.

Note that the orientation of rows/columns follows that of pandas.

Example
-------
import numpy as np
onedim = np.arange(20)
twodim = onedim.reshape((5,4))

print(twodim)
[[ 0  1  2  3]
 [ 4  5  6  7]
 [ 8  9 10 11]
 [12 13 14 15]
 [16 17 18 19]]

print(rwindows(onedim, 3)[:5])
[[0 1 2]
 [1 2 3]
 [2 3 4]
 [3 4 5]
 [4 5 6]]

print(rwindows(twodim, 3)[:5])
[[[ 0  1  2  3]
  [ 4  5  6  7]
  [ 8  9 10 11]]

 [[ 4  5  6  7]
  [ 8  9 10 11]
  [12 13 14 15]]

 [[ 8  9 10 11]
  [12 13 14 15]
  [16 17 18 19]]]
"""

if window > a.shape[0]:
    raise ValueError('Specified `window` length of {0} exceeds length of'
                     ' `a`, {1}.'.format(window, a.shape[0]))
if isinstance(a, (Series, DataFrame)):
    a = a.values
if a.ndim == 1:
    a = a.reshape(-1, 1)
shape = (a.shape[0] - window + 1, window) + a.shape[1:]
strides = (a.strides[0],) + a.strides
windows = np.squeeze(np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(a, shape=shape,
                                                     strides=strides))
# In cases where window == len(a), we actually want to "unsqueeze" to 2d.
#     I.e., we still want a "windowed" structure with 1 window.
if windows.ndim == 1:
    windows = np.atleast_2d(windows)
return windows
```

thank you all!

Alessandro

Answer (score 0):

I am struggling with this myself at the moment using PandasRollingOLS. I came to the temporary conclusion to simply take care of it before the regression, i.e. delete every column with below min_window value before running regressions.

```
min_window = 3
df.loc[:,~(df.rolling(min_window).count() < min_window).all()]
```

Note that it requires that your dataframe has NaNs (which is why I guess you want to have a min_window):

```
NaN NaN
0.5 NaN
0.8 NaN
0.7 0.5
0.6 0.4
```

This might be a temporary (ugly) solution until a Python guru stumbles upon your post.

Comment: hi, thanks for your reply!
i would like to have min_window in the rollingOLS function, because if we have a window of 90 it does not perform OLS on first 90 values.
i would like to perform a OLS expanding until 90 observations starting when there is at least 12 observation (min_window), then rolling of 90 (window)